# AWS IAM Policy - allow from IP Addresses AND allow Firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-iam, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm trying to set up an ES instance that allows access from a couple of IP addresses, in addition to allowing a Kinesis Firehose IAM role to deliver data to the instance.

I'm having trouble combining the two policies though. Each one works on its own. With just the IP address policy in place, I can view ES from Kibana, but I can't deliver data with Firehose. Likewise with only the Firehose policy, I can deliver data but not query ES.

Can someone help me see my error in constructing this access policy?

Here's the policy on the ES instance:

```
"Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::iiiiiiiiiiii:role/firehose_delivery_role"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-2:iiiiiiiiiiii:domain/es-test/*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-2:iiiiiiiiiiii:domain/es-test/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx",
            "yyy.yy.y.yyy"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
]
```

Comment: Where have you been putting this policy? On a role? On ES? If you separate the policy, does each half work correctly?

Comment: On ES - and yes, each half of the policy works as expected

Comment: Do you really have `"Sid": ""` here, or did you redact this?

Comment: That was like that in the original policy - I changed to have a value. Strange that AWS would allow that policy

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the following prior to the Statement:     "Version": "2012-10-17",
2. For your source IP's, have you specified a subnet mask like /32 or /24?  It's required per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Conditions_IPAddress
3. Add a unique "Sid" to the first statement, you have one for the 2nd statement.  Documentation says it's optional, however I have a working policy very close to yours except for these differences.